# What's the Python/pandas equivalent to this SQL for finding both the max value and column-name?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, max

What is the python/pandas equivalent of a `MAX(variable)` statement like:

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Table5 WHERE 
Friend_count = (SELECT MAX(friend_count) FROM Table5);
```

(I am trying to learn how to do some things in Python that I would normally do in SQL. I would think I could do this in pandas, but not finding a way.)

Comment: **RTFM**! http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: The equivalent of `max()` in python is `max()`. I am really not sure what else would you want? Clarify the question or see the docs above.

Comment: Off-topic: No showing research attempts at all.

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have a `pandas` `DataFrame` in which you're trying to find the maximum of a `friend_count` column, or are you working with some native Python data structure?

Comment: @DSM five years on and the OP didn't say, but since they ask about working with tables, it's reasonable to assume they're working with a pandas DataFrame(/Series)

Comment: @PeterVaro, sashkello the OP's example showed they wanted both the max value and its column-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the `idxmax()` method on your `DataFrame`?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ggplot import meat
```

I'm using the meat data set in [ggplot](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot) here.

```
In [18]: meat
Out[18]:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 827 entries, 0 to 826
Data columns (total 8 columns):
date               827  non-null values
beef               827  non-null values
veal               827  non-null values
pork               827  non-null values
lamb_and_mutton    827  non-null values
broilers           635  non-null values
other_chicken      143  non-null values
turkey             635  non-null values
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(7)
```

Suppose you want to find the row or rows where `beef` production was the highest.

```
In [36]: meat.beef.max()
Out[36]: 2512.0
```

In SQL you might do

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    meat 
WHERE
    beef = (SELECT max(beef) FROM meat) ;
```

With pandas you can accomplish this using idxmax like so:

```
In [35]: meat.ix[meat.beef.idxmax()]
Out[35]:
date               2002-10-01 00:00:00
beef                              2512
veal                              18.7
pork                              1831
lamb_and_mutton                   19.7
broilers                        2953.3
other_chicken                     50.7
turkey                           525.9
Name: 705, dtype: object
```

`idxmax` is pretty great, and it should also work if your data is date or time based.

```
In [42]: ts = meat.set_index(['date'])

In [43]: ts.beef.max()
Out[43]: 2512.0

In [44]: ts.beef.idxmax()
Out[44]: Timestamp('2002-10-01 00:00:00', tz=None)

In [45]: ts.ix[ts.beef.idxmax()]
Out[45]:
beef               2512.0
veal                 18.7
pork               1831.0
lamb_and_mutton      19.7
broilers           2953.3
other_chicken        50.7
turkey              525.9
Name: 2002-10-01 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

Comment: When applicable, this works nicely, although you can get yourself into trouble if more than one row reaches the maximum value as `idxmax` only returns the first.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a Person class. It has an attribute, friend_count. Here's an example to find the person with the most friends...

```
import operator

class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, friend_count):
        self.friend_count = friend_count

people = [Person(x) for x in [0, 1, 5, 10, 3]]
popular_person = max(people, key=operator.attrgetter('friend_count'))
print popular_person.friend_count # prints 10
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [max method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.max.html) on a pandas' Series / Column:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  3  4
```

Select the column:

```
In [3]: s = df.A  # same as df['A']
```

And take the max:

```
In [4]: s.max()
Out[4]: 3
```

You can also take the [max over the DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html):

```
In [5]: df.max() # over the columns
Out[5]: 
A    3
B    4
dtype: int64

In [6]: df.max(axis=1) # over the rows
Out[6]: 
0    2
1    4
dtype: int64
```

To return all the rows with the max value, you should use the mask:

```
In [7]: df.A == df.A.max()
Out[7]: 
0    False
1     True
Name: A, dtype: bool

In [8]: df[df.A == df.A.max()]
Out[8]: 
   A  B
1  3  4
```

Comment: Is there a better way to get the rows which reach the maximum than something like `df.loc[df.Friend_count == df.Friend_count.max(), ["ID", "Name"]]`?

Comment: @DSM I think this came up not long ago, I think it's almost always best to do just that

Answer (score 0):

In order to obtain the max value from a list in Python, simply use the `max` function. The same applies to `min`. See the documentation located [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max). If you wish to do based on a property of an object, then you can use list comprehensions like `max(person.age for person in people)`.

If you wish to obtain the person with the highest age, then you can use a list comprehension like

```
oldest_age = max(person.age for person in people)
people_with_max_age = [person for person in people if people.age == oldest_age]
```

Unlike SQL, you rarely want to collect just n properties of an object - it's much more useful to keep them attached on the object, and make collections of the objects you want. If you want to achieve that, see @FogleBird's answer.

Comment: That'll give you the max age (integer value), but not the person instance that has the max. See my answer.

Comment: His example only gets the highest friend count - my example is fine for exactly that.

Comment: His example gets the ID and Name.